# React native ScrollView Issue with content size

Tags: react-native

I am having layout issue with ScrollView
When I use View it was displaying like this.
http://collabshot.com/show/Kis4aJ

http://pastebin.com/Yagt8X38

When I changed it to scrollview
http://collabshot.com/show/f3lEtM

http://pastebin.com/zK0HnjaN

And here are the styles

```
content: {
    flex: 1,            
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingRight: 10,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: '#000000',

  },
  transmit: {
    height: 100,    
    borderWidth: 1,    
  },

  messages: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ffff00',

  }
```

Looking for help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to set a height on the container around your ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

I guess in ScrollView we need to use three major things

1. style
2. contentContainerStyle
3. automaticallyAdjustContentInsets ==> either true/false according to your scenario.(An important one to set the contents inside the ScrollView)